# Use modal view as "normal" view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to use a modal view (`UIViewController`) as a "normal" view, which can be pushed on the navigation controller stack. Normally, a modal view is presented like this:

```
LoginViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[myView release];
myView = nil;
[navController release];
navController = nil;
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

The problem is that my modal view has a right and a left button. So I would have to check how the view is loaded and present the buttons in another way. The idea behind this is to have the back button. So I can use the same modal view a few times.

**Edit:**

@petert:

Now I followed your example. My issue is that I'm using a `UINavigationBar` for the modal view. To get this `UINavigationBar` I create a navigation controller. I'm using the navigation bar because I have my buttons in it. So checking if `parentViewController` is of type `UINavigationController` does not work for me. I'm always getting a modal view. Here is how I do it:

```
// load modal view
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
navController = nil;
[myView release];
myView = nil;


// load as normal view
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good tips in this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652801/reusing-uiviewcontroller-for-modal-and-non-modal-situations).

I prefer to use [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *parentViewController
```

in a view controller's subclass:

> Look at the value of the controller's `parentViewController` property. If it's an instance of `UINavigationController`, then you're in the navigation stack. If you're being displayed modally, it'll be an instance of your last view controller.

So in `-viewDidLoad` for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   if ([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
     {
        // navigation controller
        self.title = @"...";
     }
   else
     {
        // modal
        self.title = @"Modal";

        // add cancel and done buttons now...
     }
}
```

**Or**, a pretty simple solution would be to customize your `init` method to your `MyViewController` class to encode your intent for the view controller.

Add the following to the `MyViewController` header:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
  BOOL modal;
}

- (id)initForModal:(BOOL)isModal;

@end
```

Now in the implementation file:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL modal;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize modal;

- (id)initForModal:(BOOL)isModal;
{
  if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil])
    {
      self.modal = isModal;
    }

  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  if (self.modal)
    {
      // add cancel and done buttons …
    }
  else
    {
      // assuming we're presented from a navigation view …
    }
}
```

Now to use this modally:

```
// load modal view
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] initForModal:YES];
```

Or not modally:

```
// load as normal view
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] initForModal:NO];
```

I'm assuming you're creating the view controller(s) from NIBs, but as always see the [View Controller Progamming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1) and especially the section titled "Defining a Custom View Controller Class".

Comment: Thank you for your provided sample code. I think it would work well, but I'm using a `UINavigationController` to present my modal view. Why I'm doing it is explained in my edited question. Perhaps you could provide a solution.

Comment: Your support is great! This solution is quite simple and works well. Now some question for my understanding: 1) Why are doing a new interface declaration in the implementation file? 2) The `if` in the `initForModal` calls the super constructor and if he is successful he returns the object (`ViewController`) and if not he returns nil. Is this correct? In the `if` statement only a option is set if the object is not nil. 3) I need the property here because the variable is used above method borders?

Comment: Glad it's helpful - 1) it's to hide the modal property, since it's not for use outside this classes implementation; 2) Yes absolutely, it's a general obj-c style for init methods; 3) I used a property just to make things simpler, I think the answer to your question is yes?  Remember to vote the answer up too, if it's helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification: myView isn't modal. You just present it as a modal one.

If you just push it into a UINavigationController hierarchy it will behave like a "normal" one.

You can't push the same view controller onto the navigation stack several times. Just once.

Also see this for how to customize the view:

[SO modal question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652801/reusing-uiviewcontroller-for-modal-and-non-modal-situations)

Comment: OK, I present it as modal view. Do you have an example for a "real" modal view? I don't want to push it at the same time on to the stack. What do you mean with just once? I can put it as normal view on the stack, but later not as modal view?